# How to create a list based on column matches within 2 data frames? Python

Tags: python, pandas

In my actual dataset data is 35 million rows by 20 columns and data2 is 4000 rows by 10 columns. Although this code would work it would take so long that my system would time out. So I am looking for an alternate solution to run faster.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'variable1':[1,2,3,4,0,6,7], 'variable2':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'variable3':[1,200,3,4,50,6,7], 'variable4':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})

data2 = pd.DataFrame({'variable1':[2,0], 'variable2':[2,5], 'variable3':[200,50], 'variable4':[17,20]})


target = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        if (data['variable1'].iloc[i] == data2['variable1'].iloc[j]) and (data['variable2'].iloc[i] == data2['variable2'].iloc[j]):
            target.append("Yes")
        else: target.append("No")
```

```
Proper output would be:
[[1,1,1,1,"No"],
[2,2,200,2,"Yes"],
[3,3,3,3,"No"],
[4,4,4,4,"No"],
[0,5,50,5,"Yes"],
[6,6,6,6,"No"],
[7,7,7,7,"No"]]
```

Comment: 35M rows * 4K rows is 140B (billion) combinations. Can your system handle this in the first place?

Comment: No I would get an error if I would allow it to continue running. Eventually I would imagine it gets a memory error or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `MultiIndex.isin`

```
c = ['variable1', 'variable2']
data['match'] = data.set_index(c).index.isin(data2.set_index(c).index)
```

---

```
   variable1  variable2  variable3  variable4  match
0          1          1          1          1  False
1          2          2        200          2   True
2          3          3          3          3  False
3          4          4          4          4  False
4          0          5         50          5   True
5          6          6          6          6  False
6          7          7          7          7  False
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to test too many combinations (35M * 4K is 140 Billion, which is too big for pandas).

You can try with numpy, although it is still a lot of combinations and would require a lot of memory (hundreds of GB):

```
a1 = data['variable1'].to_numpy()
a2 = data['variable2'].to_numpy()

b1 = data2['variable1'].to_numpy()
b2 = data2['variable2'].to_numpy()

out = ((a1==b1[:,None])&(a2==b2[:,None])).ravel()
```

output:

```
array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False,  True, False, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df2=data.merge(data2, 
           left_on=['variable1', 'variable2'],
           right_on=['variable1','variable2'],
           suffixes=(None,'_y'),a
           how='left'
          ).drop(columns='variable4_y').rename(columns={'variable3_y':'match'})
df2['match'] = np.where(df2['match'].isnull(), 'No', 'Yes')
df2.values.tolist()
```

```
[[1, 1, 1, 1, 'No'],
 [2, 2, 200, 2, 'Yes'],
 [3, 3, 3, 3, 'No'],
 [4, 4, 4, 4, 'No'],
 [0, 5, 50, 5, 'Yes'],
 [6, 6, 6, 6, 'No'],
 [7, 7, 7, 7, 'No']]
```